# Why might the scaling of SetWindowExtEx be just wrong?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to scale images/text etc using `MM_ANISTROPIC` and what I've done is the following (by the way if the syntax is a little weird, it's originally from delphi so treat the following as pseudocode)

I would expect the following code to produce a rectangle that is 70% of the width of the PaintBox and 30% of the height, yet it doesn't, instead it it noticeably too small.

```
SetMapMode(hdc,MM_ANISOTROPIC);
SetWindowExtEx(hdc,100,100,0);
SetViewportExtEx(hdc,70,30,0);
Rectangle(hdc, 0,0,PaintBox.width-1,PaintBox.Height-1);
```

if, on the other hand I change the code so that the `SetWindowExtEx` has 91 instead of 100 as its parameters (as shown below) then it works, which makes no sense to me at all...

```
SetMapMode(hdc,MM_ANISOTROPIC);
SetWindowExtEx(hdc,91,91,0);
SetViewportExtEx(hdc,70,30,0);
Rectangle(hdc, 0,0,PaintBox.width-1,PaintBox.Height-1);
```

My sanity test case was to add the following pseudocode

```
SetMapMode(hdc,MM_TEXT);
DrawLine(hdc,Round(PaintBox.width*0.7),0,Round(PaintBox.width*0.7),PaintBox.Height-1);
DrawLine(hdc,0,Round(PaintBox.height*0.3),PaintBox.width-1,Round(PaintBox.height*0.3));
```

I would have expected this to overwrite the lower / bottom edges of my original Rectangle but it does not unless I uses that 91,91 SetWindowExtEx.

Can anyone duplicate this?

FURTHER EDIT: Here is my exact original code I had given pseudo code before to make the question more accessible to non-delphi users but one of my commenters wanted full code to see if my contention that it was a delphi quirk was true or not.

The entire project consisted of a VCL form with a rectangular paintbox dropped on it centered so there was space all around it, and its onPaint event was set to the code below resulting in [this image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT1YM.jpg):

```
procedure TForm11.PaintBox2Paint(Sender: TObject);
    var
      hdc:THandle;
      res:TPoint;

    procedure SetupMapMode;
    begin
      SetMapMode(hdc,MM_ANISOTROPIC);
      SetWindowExtEx(hdc,100,100,0);
      SetViewportExtEx(hdc,70,30,0);
    //  These lines are required when we're painting to a TPaintBox but can't be used
    //  if we're paiting to a TPanel and they were NOT in my original question but only
    //  got added as part of the answer
    //  SetViewportOrgEx(hdc,PaintBox2.Left,PaintBox2.Top,@ZeroPoint);
    //  SetWindowOrgEx(hdc,0,0,@ZeroPoint);
    end;

    begin
      //draw a rectangle to frame the Paintbox Surface
      PaintBox2.Canvas.Pen.Style:=psSolid;
      PaintBox2.Canvas.Pen.width:=2;
      PaintBox2.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clGreen;
      PaintBox2.Canvas.Brush.Style:=bsClear;
      PaintBox2.Canvas.Rectangle(0,0,PaintBox2.Width-1,PaintBox2.Height-1);
      PaintBox2.Canvas.Brush.Style:=bsSolid;

      //initialize convenience variable
      hdc:=PaintBox2.Canvas.Handle;
      SetTextAlign(hdc,TA_LEFT);

    //as doing things to the PaintBox2.Canvas via Delphi's interface tends to reset
    //everything, I'm ensuring the map mode gets set **immediately** before
    //each drawing call
      SetupMapMode;
    ///  Draw Text at the bottom of the PaintBox2.Canvas (though as it's mapped it
    ///  SHOULD be 1/3 of the way down and much smaller instead)
      TextOut(hdc,200,PaintBox2.Height-PaintBox2.Canvas.TextHeight('Ap'),'Hello, World!',13);
      PaintBox2.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clblue;
      PaintBox2.Canvas.Brush.Style:=bsClear;
    //ensure it's set before doing the rectangle
      SetupMapMode;
    // Redraw the same rectangle as before but in the mapped mode
      Rectangle(hdc, 0,0,PaintBox2.Width-1,PaintBox2.Height-1);
      PaintBox2.Canvas.Brush.Style:=bsSolid;
    //reset the map mode to normal
      SetMapMode(hdc,MM_Text);
    //draw text at the "same" position as before but unmapped...
      TextOut(hdc,200,PaintBox2.Height-PaintBox2.Canvas.TextHeight('Ap'),'Goodbye, World!',15);

    //Draw lines exactly at 70% of the way across and 30% of the way down
    //if this works as expected they should overwrite the right and bottom
    //borders of the rectangle drawn in the mapped mode
      PaintBox2.Canvas.Pen.Color:=RGB(0,255,255);
      PaintBox2.Canvas.MoveTo(Round(PaintBox2.Width*0.7),0);
      PaintBox2.Canvas.LineTo(Round(PaintBox2.Width*0.7),PaintBox2.Height);
      PaintBox2.Canvas.MoveTo(0,Round(PaintBox2.Height*0.3));
      PaintBox2.Canvas.LineTo(PaintBox2.Width,Round(PaintBox2.Height*0.3));
    end;
```

Comment: Just an aside, you want `Paintbox.Width,PaintBox.Height` instead of `PaintBox.Width-1,PaintBox.Height-1`. `Rectangle` does not include the bottom or right coordinates in the drawing.

Comment: Maybe your application is not DPI aware. See [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Drat, I thought you might be onto something but I even went so far as to set the application's compatibility properties to run it in 640x480 mode and it made no difference.  Can anyone duplicate this?  I added my test case to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I don't know WHY the following is necessary -- it may be a Delphi quirk, the fact that I'm using a TPaintBox with is a TGraphicControl rather than a Component, or if I'm missing out on some fundamental concept on how this whole mapping mode works, BUT if I add the following code:

```
ZeroPoint:=TPoint.Zero;
SetViewportOrgEx(hdc,PaintBox1.Left,PaintBox1.Top,@ZeroPoint);
SetWindowOrgEx(hdc,0,0,@ZeroPoint);
```

Then it all displays as expected.  Anyone have any explanations as to why this is necessary?

EDIT: Okay, I've got a PARTIAL explanation.  It has to do with the control I was painting on being a TPaintBox, which is a TGraphic control rather than a TWinControl.  To wit:

> TGraphicControl is the base class for all lightweight controls.
>
> TGraphicControl supports simple lightweight controls that do not need the ability to accept keyboard input or contain other controls. Since lightweight controls do not wrap Windows screen objects, they are faster and user fewer resources than controls based on TWinControl.

As such, although they APPEAR to have a separate canvas, I have this sneaking feeling that they are really sharing the form's canvas which is why, when I switched to a TWinControl descendant, which DOES own its own Windows DC, then the display worked as expected without setting the ViewpointOrg.

So it was a Delphi quirk after all...!

Comment: It's not a *Delphi quirk*. Delphi does not interfere with or affect direct WinAPI calls.

Comment: Actually, I've determined that it is (a Delphi quick)!  This issue was indeed with the TPaintBox component, although it appears to have a completely isolated canvas, it apparently isn't truly so.  When I replaced the drawing surface with a TPanel whose paint routine I overrode then the issue went away and the `SetViewportOrgEx(hdc,PaintBox1.Left,PaintBox1.Top,@ZeroPoint);
SetWindowOrgEx(hdc,0,0,@ZeroPoint)` caused exactly the problem you'd suspect them to... in other words, offsetting where the scaled image started.

Comment: I still don't think it's a Delphi quirk. I think it''s an issue with your code, but you've failed to provide an MCVE in either the question or the answer where it can be proven either way. TPaintBox is designed **specifically** to be drawn on (which is why it was named TPaintBox). In both your question and answer you've posted snippets of out-of-context, incomplete code; the problem may be in the code you've not included.

Comment: I've edited the original version to include the full painting code -- the form consisted purely of a paintbox in the middle of the form with the PaintBox's OnPaint property set to the function listed above.  However as I mentioned in my previous comment,  if you take a TWinControl descendant such as TPanel and make its OnPaint Public and set it to use the same code above **_without_** the "SetViewPointOrg" call then it works correctly.

Comment: So if you take a *TWinControl* and use **different code** (without the `SetViewPointOrg` call) it works? OK. Different code behaves differently with different controls. Really?

Comment: Yes.  If I use the EXACT SAME code as above (the one that produces the weird result that initiated this question) but draw to a tPanel's Canvas instead of a TPaintBox's canvas it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm now confused. You said *If you take a TWinControl descendent...and set it to use the same code **without** the SetViewPointOrg call then it works*, but your question is about TPaintBox **with** the SetViewPointOrg code, and now you're saying **the EXACT SAME code**. Which is it? One is with, one is without, and they're clearly not **exactly the same** because **one is with** and **the other is without**.

Comment: My original code used a TPaintBox and did NOT use SetViewPointOrg and it produced erroneous results.  If I take a TPanel Descendant and use it in place of the TPaintBox and make no changes to original code, it produces the CORRECT results.